# random placement of fields in view openerp

Tags: openerp-7

i have created a new module name "activity code" in openerp, my issue is that in view i am getting all fields and that too in random sequence,

how can i manage fields in view so that they appear in a defined sequence  ?

Below is my code

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm

class activityCode(orm.Model):
    _name = 'bbw.activity'
    _columns = {
    'activitycode' : fields.char('Acitivity code', size=70, required = True, translate=True),
    'status' : fields.boolean('Inactive'),
    'name' : fields.char('Activity Name',size=70),
    'type' : fields.selection([('hourly','Hourly'),('nonhourly','Non-hourly')],'Type'),
    'chargestatus' : fields.selection([('charge','Chargeable'),('noncharge','Non-chargeable')],'Status'),
    'rate' : fields.selection([('employeebilling','Use Employee Billing Rate'),('customerbilling','Use Customer Billing Rate'),('activityrate','Use Activity Rate')],'Rate'),
    'level' : fields.char('Level',size=30),         
    }
    _sql_constraints = [
    ('name_uniq_1', 'unique(activitycode)', 'Activity code must be unique!')
    ]

activityCode()


<?xml version="1.0"?>

<openerp>
 <data>


<record id="action_bbw_activity" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Activity codes</field>
    <field name="res_model">bbw.activity</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <field name="activitycode" />
        <field name="status" />
        <field name="name" />

      </field>
</record>



<menuitem id="bbw_parent" name="BBW" icon="terp-partner"/>
<menuitem id="menu_office_parent" name="Activity" parent="bbw_parent"></menuitem>
<menuitem action="action_bbw_activity" id="menu_bbw_activity" parent="menu_office_parent" string="Result"/>


</data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your xml file,

```
 <record id="view_bbw_activity" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Activity codes form</field>
        <field name="model">bbw.activity</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="activity codes" version="7.0">
                <group>
                    <field name="activitycode" />
                    <field name="status" />
                    <field name="name" />
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="action_bbw_activity" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">bbw.activity</field>
        <field name="res_model">bbw activity</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_bbw_activity"/>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="bbw_parent" name="BBW" icon="terp-partner"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_office_parent" name="Activity" parent="bbw_parent"/>
    <menuitem action="action_bbw_activity" id="menu_bbw_activity" parent="menu_office_parent" string="Result"/>
```

Hope this will help you. and also check this link, which contains documentation related view of OpenERP. https://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_3/

Comment: Thanks a lot mansi, it works. i have one more question how can i hide a dropdown in openerp upon change in another dropdown?

Comment: sorry vaibhav, I havent seen your question. and thanks abhishek to reply onbehalf of me. Try what abhishek has said vaibhav, if you don't understand than Do inform. will help you.

Comment: i have used on_change method and  i am able to reset the value of a dropdown, on change of another dropdown, but i am unable to hide that particular dropdown. is there any way i can hide the dropdown?.

Comment: try this, use attrs in your view for dropdown. for example - attrs="{'invisible': [('invoiced', '=', 1), ('state', 'not in', ('confirmed', 'draft'))]}"